capture card number in the order activity of order page dashboard
I'm working on an offsite payment module, wherein I'm trying to capture the card number(last 4 digit) in the dashboard order activity and in payment tab just like stripe module does. For instance, I tried concatenating the "merchant_ref_number" and "card number" to appear in the order activity. Here's code that I used:
  public function onReturn(OrderInterface $order, Request $request) {
  //\Drupal::logger('commerce_payment')->notice('onReturn function called.'); 

    $amount = $request->get('amount');
    $status_code = $request->get('Status');
    $merchant_ref_number = $request->get('merchant_ref_number');
    $currencydesc = $request->get('currencydesc');
    $Requestid = $request->get('Requestid');
    $CardLast4 = $request->get('CardLast4');
    $CardType = $request->get('CardType');

    // Concatenate the merchant_ref_number and the last 4 digits
    $remote_id = $merchant_ref_number . '.' . $CardType . ' Card ending in ' . $CardLast4;

    // Create and save payment entity.
    $payment_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_payment');
    $payment = $payment_storage->create([
        'state' => 'completed',
        'amount' => $order->getBalance(),
        'payment_gateway' => $this->parentEntity->id(),
        'order_id' => $order->id(),
        'remote_id' => $remote_id,
        'remote_state' => $status_code,
    ]);

    $payment->save(); 

    // Check the status code returned from the payment gateway.
    if ($status_code == '00') {
      // Payment was successful.
       /* \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Your payment was successful. Status Code - @status / Reference number - @merchant_ref_number .', ['@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number, '@status' => $status_code]), 'status');  */

    }
    elseif ($status_code == '05') {    
    // Transaction Failed / Declined.
 
      /*  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Payment declined. Please try again with correct card details. Status Code - @status / Reference number - @merchant_ref_number', ['@status' => $status_code, '@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number]), 'error');  */

      $order->set('state', 'pending');
      $order->save();
 
    }
  }

but problem is because of concatenation, In the payment tab under 'Remote ID' column appears concatenation of "merchant_ref_number" as well as "card number which I don't want. I want both 'merchant_ref_number' and 'card number' to appear in order activity but only "merchant_ref_number" in the 'Remote ID' column.
Pls click link to see screenshot for better understanding:
https://prnt.sc/LXUZ1oyLoZta  - order activity view
https://prnt.sc/53q4vpdUE9bm  - payment tab view
I would really appreciate any help. Please
